# Python SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED using Google-Search-API

Tags: python, ssl, google-search-api

I'm using the [Google Search API](https://github.com/abenassi/Google-Search-API) in a small python program. When I have a simple function:

```
def find_url(search_term):
    result = google.search(search_term)
```

Where search_term is a string, I get the error:

```
Error accessing: http://www.google.com/search?nl=en&q=hello&start=0&num=10
<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)>
```

I'm not sure why I'm running into this error. I can't find any stackoverflow posts directly working with this Google Search API and there's no mention of ssl errors on the github.

Edit: Here is my full code

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg') #Stops crashing
from tkinter import * 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/Cactus/wiki-word-frequency/Google-Search-API')
from google import google

def find_url(search_term):
    result = google.search(search_term)
    print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    def do():
        graph.main()
    def get_text_button(): #On button click
        find_url(search.get())
    def get_text_enter(search): #On pressing enter/return
        find_url(search.widget.get())

    root =Tk()
    #root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(600, 400))
    #Make layout look good when uncommenting the above line

    title = Label(root, text="Hello tkinter!")
    title.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2)

    label = Label(root, text="Search term: ")
    label.grid(column=0, row=1)

    search = Entry(root, bd=3)
    search.bind("<Return>", get_text_enter)  
    search.grid(column=1, row=1)

    button = Button(root, text="Submit", command=get_text_button)
    button.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=1)
    exit = Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
    exit.grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=1)

    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @ResetACK I don't think any of the arguments for the 'google.search()' are related to verification. [Link to the code.](https://github.com/abenassi/Google-Search-API/blob/master/google/modules/standard_search.py)

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, are you sure it's an issue with the script?

Comment: I just posted my full code. I'm not really sure what's causing the problem, I just assumed it was from the google search API. Here, I'm just using tkinter entry box to let the user choose a search term, and when they press enter or a submit button, the program should grab the url and then do more things with python code in a separate file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the API, but I've encountered this error message using other libraries (`requests` comes to mind) to make non-secure http requests.  Note that `http://www.google.com/search?...` has `http` as a prefix as opposed to the secure and encrypted `https`.  Can't fully diagnose the problem, but perhaps this will point someone else to an answer.